# How to use one form in different HTML pages?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Assume that we have one form like this:

```
class SubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Subscriber
        fields = ('email', )
```

And our view is

```
class AddSubscriber(CreateView):
    form_class = SubscriberForm
    model = Subscriber

    def form_valid(self, form):
        subscriber = form.save(commit=False)
        subscriber.save()
        return redirect('events_list')
```

How can I use this form in many different pages?

Comment: are u sure you wrote your form in a python code?

Comment: `class Meta:` with no `()` also

Comment: it is not clear for me what do u mean in *many different pages*? Will those pages be generated by 1 view? Or by different? If by 1 - it should be working with your code. If by different - you just add that form into different views.

Comment: you could add this form in a `context_processor`, and it will be available in all templates

Comment: @Lemayzeur Thank you. it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by importing your form into other views you want to use. Assume that you have defined your form in `MyApp/forms.py` you can use it in another apps like this:

```
from MyApp.forms import SubscriberForm
```

and into other parts of `MyApp` you can import your form like this:

```
from .forms import SubscriberForm
```